# Android how to cancel clear before drawing?

Tags: java, android

```
class MyView extends View {

  @Override
  public void onDraw(Canvas c) {


      c.drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);

    }
}
```

I want to leave the previous drawings in the view content, but everytime I draw a line all the other are cleared, how can I draw many lines without deleting the previous drawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onDraw always draws from scratch, there is no way to change that.  If you want to alter the existing drawing, capture it in a Bitmap at the end of onDraw, so the next time its called you can draw that bitmap first.  The best way to do that is to have all of your drawing commands draw to a bitmap, and then your onDraw just blits that bitmap to the screen canvas at the end.